# Add a period column based on dates in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to add a period column to my dataframe based on date ranges. Below is a sample of my dataframe.

```
               story               date  sentiment  price  ccwords  CCWordsCount    fltprice
Story_Num                           
0   it was a curious choice...  2012-01-16  0       $6.68    1.0           1          6.68
1   when he was a yale ...      2013-04-07  0       $162.30  1.0           2          162.30
2   video bitcoin has real...   2013-04-11  0       $124.90  1.0           5          124.90
3   bitcoin s wild ride may...  2013-04-14  0       $90.00    1.0          7          90.00
4   amid the incense cheap...   2013-05-06  1       $112.30  0.0           0          112.30
5   san francisco eight...      2013-05-29  0       $132.30  1.0           1          132.30
```

So I'd like to add a column "period" where any row with dates between January 2009 and April of 2013 to be period 1, May of 2013 to December of 2017 to be period 2, and anything after January of 2018 to be period 3.

I've tried variations on

```
df9['period'] = '1' if df9['date'] < '4/30/2013'
```

```
df9.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 411 entries, 0 to 410
Data columns (total 7 columns):
story              411 non-null object
date               411 non-null datetime64[ns]
sentiment          411 non-null int64
 bitcoin price     411 non-null object
ccwords            411 non-null float64
CCWordsCount       411 non-null int64
fltprice           411 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 25.7+ KB
```

Comment: post the code that you have tried

Comment: I added the code I've attempted, I am SUPER new to Python and have searched for about an hour and couldn't find any answers.

Comment: print the data type of your date column, need to make sure for your comparison you are comparing the same data types.

Comment: I've added the .info() output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with datetimes:

```
bins = pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-01','2013-04-30','2018-01-31'])
df['new'] = pd.cut(df['date'], bins=bins, labels=[1,2]).cat.add_categories([3]).fillna(3)
```

Or [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['date'].between('2000-01-01','2013-04-30')
m2 = df['date'].between('2013-05-01','2018-01-31')

df['new'] = np.select([m1, m2], [1,2], default=3)
```